# Find duplicate across sheet based on multiple columns google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to match a row in one sheet with row in another. (To use conditional formatting). But this match is based on multiple column.

​

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Cr13bQZ2ZZnb1Y2Nq6aMFhHXhFTZsioJ3M4S1fzURQ/edit?usp=sharing

​

Sheet 1

```
|Country|Year|Location|    
|India  |2001|D1      |
|Russia |1999|D3      |
|Kenya  |1001|D4      |    
|India  |1999|D2      |
```

​

Sheet 2

```
|Country  |Year|Destination|    
|India    |2000|DA1        |    
|Bulgaria |1999|DA3        |    
|Wakanda  |1001|DA4        |    
|India    |1999|DA2        |
```

Only `India-1999` should be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH($A2&$B2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:A")&INDIRECT("Sheet1!B2:B"))))
```

[image]